# @SpringBootTest for main class giving Postrges Communication Exception

Tags: java, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test Springboot main class for code coverage with junit5. But i am getting:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432
> refused.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class AlphaApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void main() {
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> AlphaApplication.main(new String[] {}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? You aren't testing anything that isn't already done with `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Hello I wanted to increase code Coverage for SonarQube thats why included as part of test

Comment: Adding a test for the single line main isn't going to help, nor is it a useful test.

Comment: If you want to write an actual integration test with a PostgreSQL and not an in-memory database. Take a look at Testcontainers (https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/). This allows you to spawn any Docker container and use it for your tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you tagged the question with `junit5`, so I assume you are using Junit5.
With v5, you shouldn't use the `@RunWith` annotation ([source])[1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

Secondly, you should not run your main method in the test! The `SpringBootTest` annotation already starts everything! Please read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) on testing Spring Boot Applications. When you generate a new project with start.spring.io, it will provide you with a basic unit test, which starts an application context. It should look just like this:

```
// Includes omitted for brevity
@SpringBootTest
class AlphaApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

That's all. The rest is Spring "magic".

For more, see the [Spring Guides](https://spring.io/guides/) on testing, e.g., "[Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)"

Also, for testing you usually don't want to use the "real" database. Spring Boot comes with some auto-configuration to use an H2 In-Memory-Database for testing. All you need to do is include the relevant dependencies in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can also use normal Spring Boot configuration for this, by using an applications.properties only for tests in `test/resource/application-test.properties`

Comment: Thank you for fast response.